# How to use わめかれた？

Tags: suffixes, passive-voice

As like this 泣きわめかれた。　I know it has to do with crying.

[image: 泣きわめかれた]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reply to [this comment by @A.Ellett](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/50421/how-to-use-%e3%82%8f%e3%82%81%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8c%e3%81%9f#comment88170_50422), 泣きわめかれた is Suffering Passive (迷惑の受身), a kind of Indirect Passive (間接受身).

泣きわめく is a compound verb (複合動詞) made of 泣く "cry" + わめく "yell", as the other poster said.

泣きわめく is an intransitive verb and doesn't take a direct object (～～を). It doesn't take an indirect object (～～に), either. This kind of verbs cannot be passive in Direct Passive structure, but can be passive in Indirect Passive/Suffering Passive structure.

Indirect Passive expresses that an action of the agent (動作主; marked by ～に)  affects/influences the subject of the sentence in some way. 泣きわめかれた means/implies "(Someone) wailed and it affected me in some way". Here in your context it means "You wailed (and it annoyed me / it detained me)".

Examples of Suffering Passive:

> - 子どもに**泣かれた**。
>     A child cried (and it bothered me.)
> - 妻に**死なれた**。
>     My wife up and died on me.
> - 夜中に上の階でピアノを**弾かれた**。
>     Someone played piano on the upper floor in the middle of the night (and it bothered me).

Note that these can't be directly transformed into the active voice; we don't say 子どもが私を/に泣く, 妻が私を/に死ぬ, etc.

For more about 迷惑の受身, See [Wikipedia 日本語の受け身-間接受身-迷惑の受身](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%97%E5%8B%95%E6%85%8B).

This thread would also be of help: [How to interpret indirect passives?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15933/9831)

Comment: この回答 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11842/9831 の下の方、「補足」でちょっと触れましたが、もっとまとまった「迷惑受身」に関するスレッドが見つかりません。

Comment: けっこう説明してきてる気ぃすんねんけど。

Comment: これ見つけた ⇒　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15933/9831

Answer (score 3):

"泣きわめかれた" is the passive form of "泣きわめいた" that is the past tense of "泣きわめく". "泣きわめく" is a word that "泣く" and "わめく *yell, shout, scream*" are combined, so it represents more intense than each of them. "泣きわめく" is defined as *to bawl one's head off*, *to bawl one's eyes out* and *to cry out* in my dictionary.

**Edit:**
According to the comments to my answer, there seems to have been some misinterpretation for the context or the situation of the manga story.
I'll clarify the situation.

There were two characters and a dog in the story. They were Yamazaki-kun and a woman with glasses, and a dog named John kept by her. 
Yamazaki-kun and she drank with other peers last night. She drank too much and seemed to lose her sanity.

She forcibly brought Yamazi-kun to her home thinking Yazaki-kun was her dog John. She took Yamazaki-kun for her dog, so she let the dog (actually Yamazaki-kun) make various kinds of tricks like **[お手]{te}** or **[お座り]{suwari}** that are very ordinary tricks taught to dogs in Japan.

When Yamazaki-kun was about to leave her home, she cried out to the dog (actually to Yamazaki-kun). Perhaps she cried out like "Hey John, do not get out or where are you going?."

Yamazaki-kun heard her **cry out 泣きわめく**. So the author wrote that Yamazaki-kun **was cried out 泣きわめかれた** in a passive form and in a past tense.

It's a very simple phrase if you think it in Japanese not in English.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might help improve the answer if you could explain the meaning of the passive verb.  In English, "I had my head bawled off" sounds a bit strange.

Comment: I'm from the UK. I think "I had my head bawled off" sounds perfectly natural. "I got my head bawled off" would be a little better, but it's still passive.

Comment: @user3856370 Who exactly is doing the crying?  Isn't it the woman?  I'm still a bit fuzzy on the passive part.  Care to elaborate your comment?  A passive-causative would make more sense to me.....

Comment: To be honest I didn't actually read the context. I was merely commenting on the phrase "I had my head bawled off". Sorry for the confusion.