# Why 気にされる instead of 気にする?

Tags: meaning, passive-voice

These two characters are discussing ヒューバート in the below, and about how he lacks self awareness. However I am not sure why 気にされる was used instead of 気にする here. I know that される can be used as an honorific version of する. However knowing the character that is talking, I highly doubt that this is an honorific usage (although I could be wrong)

> ヒューバート「あんまり偉い人が来ないなら俺たちも気楽で良いな」
>
> Person 1「ヒューバートって自分の立ち位置をよく理解していないわよね」
>
> Person 2「まあ、気にされるよりは良いだろう」

Comment: Don't forget that される can also be the passive-form of する

Comment: That is true, but I understood that they are talking about ヒューバート, so I am not quite sure how I would interpret passive in this case.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50421/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15933/5010

Comment: Check out https://tap-biz.jp/business/honorific/1039076 The keigo consultant explains that 気にされる and 気になさる are acceptable polite forms of 気にする. Two more opinions weigh in here https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1022847125 I would add that sometimes honorifics are used in a mocking / sarcastic way.

Comment: @Rick, No, the 気にされる here is not honorific.

Comment: gambit is right. Two person are talking about Hubert. So they don't make sense to use passive. But in casual conversation, we often use unproper Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get much of the context, nor how the character's attitudes relate to each other, but I were to say something,「気にされる」is used to infer that "...it's better for ヒューバート to not take notice of **Person 1** and **Person 2** (because it could be 面倒くさい, awkward, clunky, faux pas...etc for them).

気にされる action comes from ヒューバード, and it's better for him to not come and take notice of Person 1 and 2 because it's meddlesome, fearful (whatever the emotion is here). If ヒューバードー doesn't come, we can maintain our 気楽-like state.

To better understand 気にされる、think of a student being looked down up by a teacher. There is a power difference here, a hierarchical difference, and although you may not be able to disagree with your teacher directly, you have alternate means of talking behind the teacher's back to avoid confrontations. Although Western culture values individualism and directness, Japanese value harmony and group cohesion, hence a tendency to be in a state of 気にする when the hierarchical nature of the Japanese culture makes it difficult to express your own opinion.

So they are 「気にする」（気にしている）, but they expressed it in a way that, simply stated, "that it would be bothersome/troublesome/meddlesome/気にする" to be 気にされる by ヒューバート (assuming he is of higher status). This is supported by the first sentence: 「あんまり偉い人が来ないなら俺たちも気楽で良いな」

Apologies for redundancies, but I hoped it served to help you understand!