# why is this verb passive in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

> まるで耳元で鳴**かれている**かのようだった。

Why is that?  How would it change if i just said 鳴いている?

Comment: Without more context, this is difficult to answer definitively. My own subjective take on this is that the speaker is being cried at, not doing the crying themselves. Look up the "suffering passive", that might help too.

Comment: Related, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50421/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15933/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that writer wanted to emphasize how closely **the writer felt to be sung (barked, chirped, etc) to** by whatever it is that's making the sounds.

If changed to 鳴いているかの　then it emphasizes how closely **the singing** or whatever making the sounds appeared to be.

Consider these examples below.

抱｛だ｝く - To hug

抱｛だ｝かれる - To be hugged

The former is not passive since you are hugging something.  The latter is passive because you are being hugged by something.  The same logic applies to the 鳴く and 鳴かれる