# Understanding されて返ってくる

Tags: grammar, manga

For context in the below panel, the girls just took photos together and is heading home. I have trouble understanding the nuance of ...されて返ってくる.

[image]

Why されて not して? Why it is passive? Also what 返ってくる means? Does it mean she receives a modified two-shot photo?

---

P.S. Does 諦めている means already quit?

Comment: I forgot to include あきらめている is more simply like 'I gave up', which means the girl does not care about (or gave up) beautifying (retouching) her own image in the photo. (It's like, 'I don't complain about my own skin as taken in the photo')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing is that the subject of 返ってくる is ツーショ, photo of two girls (Yuzu and the one who is speaking) and it is more natural to use passive (photo is affected by 顔ちっちゃくする and not doing 顔ちっちゃくする).

Another thing is so-called 迷惑の受け身 as mentioned e.g. in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/50421/how-to-use-%E3%82%8F%E3%82%81%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F/50432#50432). The sentence suggests that Yuzu always makes the size of her own face smaller than the speaker's, which kind of annoys the speaker. ('I'm damaged by making my own face relatively bigger than Yuzu's'.)