# Qualifying Nouns With verbs and adjectives in japanese

Tags: grammar, verbs, adjectives, nouns

If possible could someone explain this to me? I have the Genki I book that explains it pretty well but I guess I'm still having difficulty grasping it. I'll leave a example sentence in case my question is unclear.

Ex.

> あそこ で ほん を よんでいる がくせい は みちこさん です

I get that あそこ で ほん を よんでいる is qualifying がくせい but what is that part of the sentence and when would I use it?

I think what may be confusing me is the different sentence structure then what I've been use to seeing thus far in what I've studied although I know Japanese sentence structure does tend to be a little more "loose" than English.

Apologies for the unclear question yet again. It seems I'm terrible at asking questions

Comment: `あそこで本を読んでいる学生はみちこさんです`
The student reading the book over there is Michiko.
I still don't understand exactly what you are asking...

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking.  Can you tell us the parts you ***do*** understand or which part specifically you don't understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a relative clause.  We have them in English, too:

> 〔あそこで　ほんを　よんでいる〕**がくせい**は　みちこさんです。
>
> The **student** [*who* is reading the book over there] is Michiko.

In Japanese, you don't have words like *who* in relative clauses, but apart from that, it's pretty similar.  In both languages, the relative clause corresponds to a main clause:

> **がくせい**は　あそこで　ほんを　よんでいる。
>
> The **student** is reading the book over there.

In each case, the subject is pulled out ("relativized") and moved outside the clause.

I wrote a longer explanation comparing relative clauses in English and Japanese [in another answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14541/relative-clauses-distinguishing-whom-with-which-that/14550#14550).  It's not perfect, but if you'd like to read more, you can see what I wrote there.