# Meaning of おともだちになるあくしゅ

Tags: meaning, spoken-language, relative-clauses

> ありがとう。それでね、これがあくしゅ、なの。
>
> あくしゅ？
>
> そう。**おともだちになるあくしゅ**。
>
> そうなんだ。うん、ことばでおしえてもらったときよりも、わかったきがする。
>
> なんていうのかな、あなたのこと、みぢかにかんじる。
>
> ねぇ、もしかしておともだちになるって、こういうこと？
>
> うん、そうだよ。そのとおりだよ。
>
> わぁ。じゃあ、わたしたち、**これで**おともだちに――

Context: Kid one is trying to become friends with kid two, kid two doesn't understand what being friends means.

My question is about the meaning of **おともだちになるあくしゅ** and to what **これで** refers to in this exchange.

おともだちになるあくしゅ- おともだちになる means to "become friends" and あくしゅ means a handshake. Now my question is how to interpret what this actually means. Does a おともだちになるあくしゅ refer to a handshake which signifies that they have become friends?

My next question is about the これで. Does this refer back to the handshake they did earlier or does it refer to their several lines after this? It's clear that she still didn't quite grasp what it meant to be friends and then clarifies it by asking if what she feels is what it means to become friends, and then after being told she is right, she then says the final line.

Comment: Related: [Relative clauses distinguishing whom/with which/that](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14541/7810)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> お友だちになる握手 = A handshake (of) when we become friends. / to become friends.

So, 【これで】 refers to the the previous act. To fully understand the expression, you have to know exactly what 【これ】 and the particle 【で】 mean.

【これ】 refers to the previous topic that the 【話し手】 was talking about, so the handshake and all, and 【で】 is used as the particle of "way".

So it can be translated as "with this", "so, ...".