# Adjective use of たかだか

Tags: grammar, adverbs, particle-で

> **たかだか**[髪]{かみ}が[伸]{の}びたくらいで。

I'm thinking たかだか髪 means roughly "very long hair". If so, I imagine the sentence would translate to "Very long hair grew about to that point." But, that doesn't make sense. "Hair grown like that is very long."  might make more sense, but would be another pointless and obvious statement that a writer would be unlikely to write. The context, where the speaker is pondering the state of his friend's hair, would warrant something more like "His hair has grown quite long." I'm not sure, though, especially with the ending で.

Answer (score 2):

たかだか is an adverb and has **no** adjective use.

- たかだか**と** — highly; aloft; sonorously
- たかだか (without と) — merely; no more than; at most

Comment: So, if たかだか is modifying 伸びた, "(His) hair grew no more than approximately that much."?

Comment: Um, close but no. How do you understand the くらい?

Comment: I thought it meant about or approximately.

Comment: It's a possible translation, but the most basic definition of the word is "degree/level".

Comment: His hair grew to that point.

Comment: "This much of thing such that his hair has grown". See [this answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/7810) or [this link](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=5kX1O4bCx_oC&lpg=PA153&ots=4qqys4OevT&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q&f=false) (hope Google Books won't reject you) for how Japanese relative clauses act like.