# Parsing potential phrase modifying a noun

Tags: passive-voice, relative-clauses, potential-form

[From Hirameki Hatsume-chan Vol 1, chapter 7[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g2Az.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g2Az.jpg)
How does the sentence in the third panel translate, and who is doing what to whom? Is it a potential and the どうぐ is "enabling" him to have good dreams or is it passive and the 見る verb used to mean "show"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ［（私が/人が）いい夢を見られる］道具
>   A tool [with which (I/people) can see a good dream]

いい夢を見られる is a relative clause modifying 道具.
Its non-relative equivalent would be:

> 道具**で**（私が/人が）いい夢を見られる。
>   With a tool, (I/people) can see a good dream.

So the 見られる is potential. Its subject can be "I", "we", "you" or "people" who will have a good dream using that tool. The particle で goes missing when you turn the sentence into the relative clause.

Compare:

> - 私がペン**を**使った。-- I used the pen.
>     → ［私が使った］ペン -- the pen that I used (を goes missing)
> - 道具**で**火を起こす。 -- (I) start a fire with a tool.
>     → ［火を起こす］道具 -- a tool with which (I) start a fire (で goes missing)
> - 筆**で**きれいな字が書ける。 -- (I) can write beautiful characters with a brush.
>     → ［きれいな字が書ける］筆 -- the brush with which (I) can write beautiful characters. (で goes missing)

Comment: How do you figure out what the modified noun would do in the original sentence, or do you just go by what makes the most sense in the context ?

Comment: @TheComputerist You'd have to just go with what makes the most sense. For more on this topic, you can refer to this thread: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14541/relative-clauses-distinguishing-whom-with-which-that

Answer (score 0):

> How does the sentence in the third panel translate?
>   いい夢{ゆめ}を見{み}られる道具{どうぐ}か・・・

Well, this is an instrument that enables you to have good dreams...

> who is doing what to whom?

道具 is enabling the person who uses/possesses the 道具 to have good dreams.

> Is it a potential and the どうぐ is "enabling" him to have good dreams or is it passive and the 見る verb used to mean "show"?

It is a potential and the どうぐ is "enabling" him to have good dreams.