# Meaning of 「～でも～でもない」?

Tags: grammar, translation, phrases

I have been translating mini comics to practice my Japanese and I came across this sentence:

> 仲間でも家族でもないそれは魅力的に映った、とても。

What exactly do they mean? I know the meaning of the words and kanji but I can't translate it because I don't understand. I think it may mean, "neither friends (comrades) nor family, that seemed very attractive," quite literally. Can someone give me a proper translation and/or explanation of how exactly this sentence works?

Comment: Context? What does the それ refer to?

Comment: @Chocolate That's exactly how the sentence is. Right after it they say, "友だちってなんだ?"

Comment: @Chocolate It's also at the beginning of the comic, so there's nothing prior to it.

Comment: The sentence literally means "That thing, which was neither friend nor family, looked very attractive." **Edit**  Oh, okay.. so "that thing" has not revealed its identity yet..

Comment: @Chocolate They're probably talking about friends, since it's the main idea of the comic.

Comment: そうですね・・ "It (=友達) was neither comrade nor family, and looked very attractive." って言ってるのかも。。

Comment: I think this sentence is unnatural.

At a minimum, the author should add "が".

"仲間でも家族でもない**が**、それは魅力的に映った、とても。"

"**それは**仲間でも家族でもない**が、私の目には**とても魅力的に映った。"
"**それは**仲間でも家族でもない**が、私には**とても魅力的に**見えた**。"

Comment: @Rohan この文だけで判断してはいけないと思います。「仲間や家族でないからこそ（煩わしくなくて）魅力的」という可能性もあるので。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know Japanese relative clauses yet, please [learn them first](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010). If you already know relative clauses, 仲間でも家族でもない is just another relative clause that modifies それ (="it"). ～でも～でもない is simply "to be neither ～ nor ～".

If it's really the very first sentence of the story, no one can understand what それ refers to at this point. Probably それ will be explained later in the story.

> 仲間でも家族でもないそれは魅力的に映った、とても。
>   It, being neither "buddy" nor "family", appeared attractive, really.

Comment: If ～ is a noun (and で isn't a separate particle) how does ～でも～でもない differ from ～も～もない? To clarify I understand why there is a で in バスでも車でも行けない, but not in the OPs example.