# Trying to understand strange lyrics in a certain song

Tags: song-lyrics

The song is 僕は頑張るよっ by 神聖かまってちゃん。

The lines that I find confusing are "*あーでもないこーでもない* 人間はめんどくさい" and "*パーでもないグーでもない* 悩んでばかりいます". Specifically, the first parts of each line.

In the translations of this song, that I found, different people translate these parts differently. Some translate "あーでもないこーでもない" as "*It’s neither this way nor that way*". And others translate it as "*Humans who are neither uh nor uh are annoying*".
In regard to the second line "*パーでもないグーでもない*", I've seen people translating it as "*It’s neither bad, nor good*" or just giving up and just writing "*I’m not a par or a goo*". I personally think it might be some rock-paper-scissors related analogy, as パー seems to represent paper while "グー" represents "rock".

*(Edit: perhaps I should clarify, that the confusing parts are "パー ", "グー", "あー" and "こー")*

I hope someone can explain or suggest what those lines mean and if any of the translations that I found are correct.

Comment: Related: [Meaning of 「～でも～でもない」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55812/meaning-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

Comment: for what is worth, just as the parallel you draw between  パー and グー and rock-paper-scissors, you can also draw a parallel between あー, こー and **あ**れ**こ**れ ([meaning "this and/or that"](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8C%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C))

Comment: @jarmanso7 thank you for trying to help me. The idea to draw a parallel between あー, こー and あれこれ didn't come to my mind, but it seems to totally make sense. Thank you!