# Does「豊富なタンパク質」 mean “abundant protein” and「タンパク質が豊富な」mean “rich in protein”?

Tags: relative-clauses

Trying to get a grasp of how to use the word **豊富な**, I found a phrase saying 「タンパク質が豊富な」 from a Japanese website. I’m not sure if が must be used for it to be correctly mean “protein-rich” or “rich in protein”
And then there’s my own phrase: 「豊富なタンパク質」. If I mean “abundant protein”, is this correct?

**EDIT:** The full sentence is "タンパク質が豊富な食材13選"

Answer (score 1):

豊富 is a rather simple na-adjective meaning *abundant*, and you can say both 豊富なタンパク質 and タンパク質が豊富な食材, just as you can say the following:

- 綺麗な人 a beautiful person
- 心が綺麗な人 a person with beautiful heart
- 有名な人 a famous person
- 絵が有名な人 a person whose paintings are famous
- 必要なお金 money needed
- お金が必要な人 a person who needs money

Grammatically, these ～が～な form [relative clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010) that modify a noun.

Comment: うええ？なぜにまいなすひょう？

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you found the phrase, but if you know about "conjugated part ending" of Japanese, you also know that "な" of the word of "豊富な" is used when the word is before some noun. It's called "attributive form." If you can't find noun after the word "豊富な," it must be omitted. You can infer what the noun is by reading context.

So the answers: Both expressions you proposed can be correct and “abundant protein” is also able to be translated into "豊富なタンパク質."

And you've questioned about "が," haven't you? "が" is one of Japanese postpositions, "joshi," that means the noun before itself is subject, and also you can use it to supplement noun with verb, like "relative pronoun." So precisely, "タンパク質が豊富な食材" is "ingredients which is protein-rich" or "ingredients which is rich in protein." This is the closest expression for this Japanese phrase, I think.

Comment: I didn't know about that, so I quoted it wrong. The full sentence is "タンパク質が豊富な食材13選"

Comment: And it means "13 protein-rich ingredients" or "13 ingredients rich in protein."