# I don’t understand the structure of 英語が伝わる楽しさをより多くの方へ

Tags: syntax

I found this ad/sticker in a restaurant, in a Philippine city where a large number of Japanese students study English.

> 英語が伝わる楽しさをより多くの方へ

I have no idea how to make of this statement.

I understand the individual phrases/words but not why the sentence is formed as such.

1. 伝わる楽しさ: is this a common formation (ru verb+ noun)
2. Is there another way to say this sentence? (In japanese?)

Comment: It's actually not a sentence.  There's no predicate at the end.

Comment: So it isn’t, what does this mean? I want to know about the structure of the phrase. Since it is written in that way, I assume it is intelligible and has a message.

Comment: Partly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/9831

Answer (score 3):

１．「英語が伝わる楽しさ」 is a noun phrase, where the relative clause 英語が伝わる (your English is understood) modifies 楽しさ (joy, pleasure). For "Gapless relative clauses", please refer to [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/9831).

「英語が伝わる楽しさ」 *lit.* joy where/when your English is understood → joy of making yourself understood in English

「～～楽しさをより多くの方へ」 literally means "joy (of ~~) to more people". The predicate, or verb phrase (like 届けたい or 届けます perhaps?)  is left out as implied. (This kind of omission is often used as a stylistic device in slogans, ads, lyrics, song/film titles etc. e.g. 『アルジャーノンに花束を』『まごころを、君に。』)

２． I would rephrase it as...

「英語が伝わる（ことの）楽しさを、もっとたくさんの人たちへ（届けたいです / お届けします）。」
「英語が伝わる（ことの）楽しさを、もっとたくさんの人に（感じてもらいたいです）。」
etc...