# How would you say 'a fork is a tool you eat with'?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

It's kind of a silly sentence, but I was wondering how you would get the で particle's meaning into a modified noun. Like you could say 'フォークで食べる' but how could you turn that into a noun? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, で is not used like フォークは食べるための道具. If you want to use で no matter what, you can say フォークはそれで食べるための道具, but it is wordy.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns marked by the particle で (of means) can be relativized, but saying

> ?フォークは食べる道具です。

I think would be too ambiguous. People would think "A fork is a tool you eat."

To disambiguate, you can explicitly include an object:

> フォークはものを食べる道具です。 A fork is tool you eat things with.