# Nominalized verb without の or こと

Tags: word-choice, syntax, jlpt, relative-clauses, nominalization

I saw this:

> アンさんはべんきょうをおしえるひとです。

Is this a correct sentence? I got confused with おしえる人. I thought we cannot follow a verb with another noun without nominalizing it with either の or こと. Should this be おしえるの人?

Comment: That's not nominalized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very important construction called a *relative clause*.

> [教]{おし}える[人]{ひと}
>   a person who teaches

The rule is described in detail in this question: [Relative clauses distinguishing whom/with which/that](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14541/5010)

Comment: I am so sorry I am still confused. I read the link you posted but I have some questions hope you can help. If おしえるひと is a relative clause then what is こと and の for? Are they called nominalizers? When will I know that I need nominalizers on a verb? Because おしえる is a verb and the reason why I thought I need a nominalizer is because I will use おしえる to describe 人 so in a way I use it as an adj.  what is wrong in this line of thinking?

Comment: Please check what is wrong with my understanding :

アンさんは人です - is the main sentence.

Since I want to add more info about what kind of person アンさん is I need something that will describe 人. I have the sentence 
アンさんは勉強をおしえるです (?) and I will add it to 人 so it will  be 勉強をおしえる add の to 人 because that is one noun phrase? 

Should の be added to verb if and only if it is not in a relative sentence?

Comment: @Shiniboi Use a nominalizer when you want to turn a verb into a noun. Use a relative clause when you want to use a verb as an adjective. Don't add の when you use a relative clause. Something like 教えるの人 is always ungrammatical in Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is safe to use a verb directly before a noun. There is no modification needed. If you add の after a verb, you turn it into a noun. Two nouns cannot be connected directly, there has to be a の inbetween, as in 私の本.

HTH
Zeyuan