# Meaning of もの in this sentence

Tags: meaning, relative-clauses

The sentence is:

> 芸術は思いをかたちにする**もの**

What does this mean? Does it mean "Art is about giving form to thoughts/feeling", "Art is the thing that gives thoughts/feeling form.

I am unsure of what もの means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your translation is spot-on. This もの is just "thing" and it refers to an abstract concept here.

Grammatically, 思いをかたちにする (literally "to turn thoughts/ideas into a form") is modifying もの as a relative clause. This is an example of [gap-less relative clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010) if I'm not mistaken.