# How to express the idea " a place where ..."

Tags: grammar, words

I asked this question a few hours ago but I think i phrase it incorrectly. The idea is like saying "a place where blah blah description of the place" example:

Imagine you are in a place where everybody is safe

My initial translation is: 皆さんは安全だということが場所にいると想像してください。

However I think it's wrong in some sense. If so, what lesson in Japanese grammar is this being taught? Thank you! PS Can't find it in the internet because I'm searching the wrong topic I think.

Comment: Have you learned how to modify a noun with a sentence?

Comment: How can i do that sir? What i only learned is the koto ga blah blah which i think is making the verb into noun... And so i dont think i know how to modify a noun, what topic is that in japanese, so i can look it up in the internet and learn it.

Comment: A noun-modifying clause is often called a “relative” clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a relative clause modifying 場所. This is a *huge* grammar topic in both English and Japanese. If you're totally new to this, please take time and read your textbook first. The following links should be helpful as a starter:

- [Relative clauses distinguishing whom/with which/that](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14541/5010)
- [Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese: Relative Clauses and Sentence Order](http://guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/clause)
- [Wasabi: Japanese Relative Clauses](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-relative-clauses/)

---

This part of your translation attempt is already perfectly fine:

> 場所にいると想像してください。
> Imagine that you are at a place.

For now, this makes little sense because 場所/place is too vague. You need to modify it somehow using a relative clause. In English, you add "where" and a mini-sentence (clause) *after* 'place'. In Japanese, you directly add a mini-sentence *before* 場所.

> **隕石が落ちた**場所にいると想像してください。
> Imagine you're at a place **where a meteor fell**.
>
> **誰もが安全に暮らせる**国にいると想像してください。
> Imagine you're in a country **where everyone can live safely**.

These are trivial examples of relative clauses. Once you master them, you will be able to say very complex things.

Comment: Wahhh! You're so great! Thank you so much and I appreciate the links.. It's so hard to find some stuff in the internet. They only show me stuff like "how to introduce yourself in Japanese" kind of lessons. But anyway THANK YOU SO MUCH!