# Noun+の+adjective+Noun: エネルギー消費の大きい生き方

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

> エネルギー消費の大きい生き方に敬礼
> Those who expend great energy in their lives, I salute you.‌

I've seen this pattern used several times, Noun+の+adjective+Noun, but I've never really understood if the adjective is characterizing what comes before or what comes after, besides in this case it's a い adjective. I would like to know when the adjective will characterize what is in front of you and what it will characterize in this pattern "Noun+の+adjective+Noun".

Comment: Seems applicable to English too. "Hats off to high energy consumers" - "*high* amount of energy" or "*high* population of consumers"? Kind of obvious but equally implicit, if you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

エネルギー消費の大きい is modifying 生き方 as a [relative clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010). This の is a subject marker used in relative clauses, and it's interchangeable with が. See: [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010)

Imagine this "double-subject" sentence:

> この生き方はエネルギー消費が大きい。
> As for this way of living, energy consumption is high.

From this, you can construct the following noun phrase with a relative clause:

> エネルギー消費**が**大きい生き方
> a way of living where energy consumption is high

Which is the same as:

> エネルギー消費**の**大きい生き方
> a way of living where energy consumption is high

Note that this person is saluting to the 生き方 itself, not "you" or anyone. The given translation is not wrong as a free translation, though.

Here are some simpler examples. が and の are interchangeable.

- 背が高い人
  背の高い人
  a tall person (lit. a person whose height is high)
  <sub>(cf. 彼は背が高い。 He is tall.)</sub>
- 鼻が長いゾウ
  鼻の長いゾウ
  an elephant with a long nose
- 心が美しい人
  心の美しい人
  a beautiful-minded person

Comment: つまらないことですが、「背」って、 length っていうより height っぽくないですか？

Comment: 直しました、lengthだと体長って感じですよね…