# Understanding と言う

Tags: quotes

Consider the phrase

> アリスという本

which native English speakers might understand as

> The book called "Alice"

**Question:** In English, we think of the name of the book as that which people *call* it. But I'm curious if in Japanese this is reversed, since the phrase "アリスという" seems to literally translate to something like

> speaks, "Alice"

as if the *book* is the object which is saying its name, rather than *us*.

So does the phrase "アリスという本" literally mean

> The book says "Alice"

?

Comment: The implied information is 本**を**アリスと言う (with an unspecified "general" subject) instead of 本がアリスと言う.   See [Relative clauses distinguishing whom/with which/that](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14541) for related examples.

Comment: If you want a native speaker’s “opinion”, I have never thought who is doing the “saying”.  アリスという本 simply means to me アリス and 本 refer to one same thing, or they are in apposition to use a grammatical term. In this sense, いう is usually written that way, in hiragana.

Comment: In my opinion, overthinking things like this is completely pointless. If I were you, I'd just accept that that's just how it works in Japanese and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence "アリスという本" just lacks its subject. It can be rephrased to "人々がアリスという本" (the book that people call Alice). What the implied subject means depends on context and situation.